# Can't play audio with google app engine. It works locally

Tags: javascript, html, google-app-engine, webapp2

I have a webpage with some arabic numbers and where an audio is played with mouseover action and the numbers get pronounced. It works locally in my browser but it doesn't work under google app engine.  It doesn't work locally under google app engine either but if I just run the html file it works.  Here's part of my code

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

 function playSound(soundfile) {
 document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML=
 "<embed src=\""+soundfile+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />";
 };
 </script>
```

```
<div>

    <table>
        <tr>    
            <td onmouseover="playSound('numbers/1.mp3');">واحِد</td>
            <td onmouseover="playSound('numbers/1st.mp3');">الأَوَّل</td>
            <td onmouseover="playSound('numbers/1st_f.mp3');">الأُولى</td>
            <td onmouseover="playSound('numbers/saturday.mp3');">السَّبْت</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

Here's the python code

```
import os
import webapp2
import jinja2
from google.appengine.ext import db

template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir),
                               autoescape=True)

class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write(self, *a, **kw):
        self.response.out.write(*a, **kw)
    def render_str(self, template, **params):
        t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
        return t.render(params)
    def render(self, template, **kw):
        self.write(self.render_str(template, **kw))

class MainPage(Handler):
    def get(self):
        self.render('ArabicNumbers.html')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)], debug=True)
```

And here's app.yaml

```
application: arabicbetweenyourhands
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.1"

- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

Also, here the url of the website. arabicbetweenyourhands.appspot.com. You can see the full source code there. Any ideas??  Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I visited your page, I got a 404 for http://arabicbetweenyourhands.appspot.com/numbers/4th_f.mp3

You need to add your 'numbers' directory as a static directory to your app.yaml and add the appropriate mime type, like so:

```
handlers:
- url: /numbers
  static_dir: numbers
  mime_type: audio/mp3
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I got some progress. Now when I run it locally with appengine it works as normal but on the live page, instead of playing the audio, it tries to download it with mouseover. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to set the appropriate MIME type for the files. See here, under "static directory handlers:" https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig

Comment: I tried this and didn't work. - url: /(.*\.(mid|midi|mp3|wav))
  static_files: numbers/\1
  upload: numbers/(.*\.(mid|midi|mp3|wav))  
Any ideas?

Comment: It finally worked!!!! I had to had one more line to app.yaml file you suggested. It is "mime_type: audio/mp3" please edit your answer to include that line and I will select your answer. Thank you!!!!!

Comment: Okay, added the mime type comment above.